# VBA How to properly globally initialize form and get/set values from its controls

Tags: vba, excel

I have problems with getting values from textboxes from form in my vba app. In module i have all logics subs which initialize form, presets values in it and so on:

```
Dim usf As New UserForm1   'in this case I assume that form is initialized 
                           'globally, on top of all subs, so all 
                           'files and subs in my vba project can acces to 
                           'controls in it. And it works, but every second 
                           'run raises an "Automation error"

Sub start()
                           'when I declare form here, program always 
                           'start, but none of subs can 
                           'acces to form controls. Of course in this case I 
                           'must initialize form in 
                           'every single sub. I've tried passing form as 
                           'argumend to functions, but 
                           'this not work or I do it in wrong way. Subs 
                           'can't read values from form controls. This sub 
                           'is only to presets values in sub and to show 
                           'form

On Error GoTo errMyErrorHandler

                          'here is part of code reading values from sheet
                          'and inserting this values to textboxes, labels 
                          'and comboboxes. No problem here.

usf.Show                  '//problem here when I declare my form globally. 
                          'Raises Automation error
Exit Sub

errMyErrorHandler:
 Call errorHandler(err)  'on error go to error handling sub which show 
                         'messagebox with err name

End Sub

Public Sub startRun(Optional x = 0) 'optional only for not to show this sub 
                                    'in macro's list. This is sub which 
                                    'starts when form's button start is 
                                    'being clicked
On Error GoTo errMyErrorHandler
Dim napZW, Udn, Str As Single
Dim H1, H2 As Integer

With usf                            'reading text from textboxes. It's not
napZW = CSng(.txtNapZw.Text)        'work when form is declared locally
Udn = CSng(.txtUdn.Text)
Str = CSng(.txtStr.Text)
H1 = CInt(.cbx1H.Text)
H2 = CInt(.cbx2H.Text)
End With

Call ObliczanieIP(napZW, Udn, Str, H1, H2, usf) 'sub for reading values from 
                                                'sheet
Exit Sub

errMyErrorHandler:
  Call errorHandler(err)
End Sub

Sub ObliczanieIP(napZW, Udn, Str, H1, H2, usf)
On Error GoTo errMyErrorHandler
Range("Q31").Value = napZW
Range("R31").Value = Udn
Range("S31").Value = Str
Range("S2").Value = H2
Range("S4").Value = H1

'some code here, checking correctness of inserted values. If not correct, 
'shows message box and exits this sub. No problem here.

usf.lblLtr = Range("s33").Value        'reads from sheet values and show it 
usf.lbXtr = Range("R33").Value         'in labels. Again, to work, form must 
usf.lblImax = Range("S18").Value       'be declared globally
usf.lblImediana = Range("S22").Value
usf.lblIsrednia = Range("S20").Value

Exit Sub

errMyErrorHandler:
  Call errorHandler(err)
End Sub

Public Sub errorHandler(err As ErrObject)
MsgBox err.Description & ", " & err.Number & " " & err.Source, _
   vbExclamation + vbOKCancel, _
    "Błąd: " & (err.Description)
  err.Clear
  End                   'Without end statement program runs only once when 
                        'excel is initialized or when i go to VBA editor and 
                        'i think ressetting all 'things' associated with 
                        'this program
End Sub
```

In userForm1 I have only logic to button event:

```
Private Sub btnStart_Click()
startRun
End Sub
```

The problem is, that when I initialize form in module outside any sub, (which I think should do this globally), my program works correctly, but every second run raises "Automation Error". When i  Initialize form in sub start restricted access to form and my other sub cannot access to controls in form. And when i reinitialize form in every sub which needed it, the controls are resetting. I know this is may be silly problem, but I'm new in in VBA. Thank you in advance to reply.

Comment: If the program works correctly when you initialize in module outside any sub (not sure what this means, do you mean `Public usf As UserForm`?), then you need to deal with the "Automation Error". As your question is currently asked, it's difficult to understand what is your problem.

Comment: Exactly, when I declare Public usf as new UserForm1 on top of module outside any sub, my app works correct, but very often I must deal with "Automation Error" and when i declare UserForm1 as seen on code i've posted above, error is gone, but another subs in other file can't acces to form controls, e.g. textboxes.

Comment: The strange thing is, that when I put end statement to error handler, the program will run fine (first run raises an "-2147418105 automation error", so error handler execute end statement. Every second run is fine). This situation is when i declare UserForm1 on very first module at the top of module before all subs (so form is declared globally i think).

Comment: It's still difficult to understand what the actual problem condition is, i.e., how can someone else reproduce this problem. Provide an [mcve] or concise steps to recreate (this may require producing simplified version of your code). Possibly if you're `new`ing the UserForm in each module or procedure, that could be a problem. If you're declaring it globally, then you need to have some logic to ensure it's been instantiated properly and exists at runtime, etc...

Comment: I've editied my code and whole post so maybe now it's clear what's is my problem.

Comment: If you want a global, unique instance of the userform, why don't you just use the one that VBA provides you, which has the same name as the class, i.e. `UserForm1`? I suspect that the trouble you are having is related to your instance being "unloaded".

Comment: If I do this by this way, form is not being updatet with correct values. There's no exception, program runs fine, but at the end my form isn't show values:                                                                                         
    ``With UserForm1
    lblLtr = Range("s33").Value
    lbXtr = Range("R33").Value
    lblImax = Range("S18").Value
    lblImediana = Range("S22").Value
    lblIsrednia = Range("S20").Value
    End With
    Exit Sub``

Comment: So there we are. @A.S.H you are right. Everything is okay if I'm not using ``with`` ``end with`` block but using full names eg ``UserForm1.lblImax = Range("S18")`` instead. Thank you very much for your replies.

Comment: Move the `startRun` procedure to the UserForm's code module. In that procedure, refer to `Me` instead of `usf`.

Comment: @JanKowalski  When using a `With` clause you should add a dot `.` in front of the members of the object that is the subject of `With`. for example `.lblLtr = Range("s33").Value`.

Comment: Yes, that's my fault. I didn't know that I don't have to declare form, so all errors are gone when I didn't do that. But even if now everything is okay and my code works flawlessy, I'm curious, why my old code runs fine only on every second run.